# Bootstrap dropdown not opening

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this piece of code where I try to implement a dropdown bar with bootstrap. I copied this code directly from bootstrap website but the bar is not opening. Any idea what might be wrong with it?

```
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                Dropdown
                <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: That behaviour relies on styles and scripts from bootstrap. Are those included somewhere on your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you haven't **downloaded Bootstrap**.

You could either download bootstrap or include bootstrap from a CDN. If you just want to make it easier and retrieve information from Bootstrap without having to download it, put this **CDN** inside of your `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But watch out for this! Because this CDN will not work without internet, you'll need to download bootstrap in that occasion.

If this didn't work, you could read more about the basics of bootstraps and how it works here: **https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp**

Comment: The problem was that I didn't import the javascript query. The menu worked as soon as I imported these scripts. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There does not look to be much wrong with your code, I've just had a test with a blank page and your drop-down seems to be working. Id suggest looking to see if you have any un-closed tags within the rest of your code.

[The Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMJx8.jpg)

Comment: Additionally, I was using Bootstrap 4 for your code.